# Cannot access Firestore from another country

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-firestore

I have set up an application developed using Flutter as front end and Firebase as datastore. I tested the application from my country where it worked fine. But now when I am trying to get it tested with client from another country i.e. UK, Firebase does not seem to be working. I am currently using free version of Firebase. Am I missing out on something here?

Comment: There is no global rule preventing access to Firestore from the UK, and I'm not aware of any outages specifically affecting the UK at the moment. You might want to see if the network logging for the UK based client shows anything related to their connection, or to ask them to try on another network.

Comment: I have asked 4 different people to try from 4 different regions. Not working.

Comment: Probably you already solved your problem but I still want  to ask. Did you deploy your application within an instance with only internal IP address?